# Search centre - checking and verifying results

Tags: 2013, search-results, people-search

When using the SP Search Centre and looking up people, SP is returning results that I am not expecting.  If I search location x it returns all the people that are in that location but at the end of the results is a person that should be there and there location is a different one.  I cannot see where it is referencing location x to this user.  How can I check/see why this person is being returned?

Answer (score 0):

You can not. There is no way to tell *why* or *why not* SharePoint search retuns it's results.

If you are you searaching in a single property like `location:somewhere` SharePoint will return only results with the given value in the given property. (Unless the property has been changed lately and not been crawled since.)